# Why is not event listener function called when event fired?

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

Well I have this inside `class Player`:

```
    public static function initClass():void {
        Player.loadPlayerSprite();
        Player.magnifyPlayerSpriteByNtimes(5);
        Player.playerSprite.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

        function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.RIGHT: moveRight();
                case Keyboard.LEFT: moveLeft();
                case Keyboard.DOWN: moveDown();
                case Keyboard.UP: moveUp();
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is why the function `onKeyDown()` isn't called when I press the keyboard.
You might wonder why the function `onKeyDown()` is inside function `initClass()`. It used to be a private static function but it didn't work so I put it in the `initClass()` but it didn't work, too. Thanks for advance.

Comment: Because the `playerSprite`doesn't have focus. If you click on it and then use the arrow keys, it should work. Alternatively, instead of adding the event listener to `playerSprite` add it to your `stage`, that way the event will be fired no matter what you're focused on.

Comment: Also, don't forget the `break` of your `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are adding your event listener to `Player.playerSprite` object. So, only `Player.playerSprite` object can call this listener.

If you want to attach your listener globally try this:

```
public static function initClass(): void {
    Player.loadPlayerSprite();
    Player.magnifyPlayerSpriteByNtimes(5);
    //add listener to stage
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
}

private static function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

If you want to attach your listener to `Player.playerSprite` try to focus this object:

```
public static function initClass(): void {
    Player.loadPlayerSprite();
    Player.magnifyPlayerSpriteByNtimes(5);
    //focus the object
    stage.focus = Player.playerSprite;
    Player.playerSprite.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
}

private static function onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    //do whatever you want
}
```